# Restkit crashing in iOS 8 due to a json issue?

Tags: ios, json, crash, ios8, restkit

I've read through a couple others having similar issues with RestKit and iOS 8 but none seemed related to JSON parsing.

My app had been updated for iOS 8 in October or November and has been working fine and then suddenly in late December it started crashing,(maybe from the 8.1.2 update?) apparently....but not with every RESTKit call, only with one in particular.

The stack trace is:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  1

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   iNacho                          0x0000000100124320 jk_encode_add_atom_to_buffer + 872
1   iNacho                          0x00000001001255a4 jk_encode_add_atom_to_buffer + 5612
2   iNacho                          0x00000001001255a4 jk_encode_add_atom_to_buffer + 5612
3   iNacho                          0x0000000100123bc4 -[JKSerializer serializeObject:options:encodeOption:block:delegate:selector:error:] + 984
4   iNacho                          0x00000001001237cc +[JKSerializer serializeObject:options:encodeOption:block:delegate:selector:error:] + 144
5   iNacho                          0x00000001001260d0 -[NSDictionary(JSONKitSerializing) JSONStringWithOptions:error:] + 68
6   iNacho                          0x0000000100119804 -[RKObjectSerializer serializedObjectForMIMEType:error:] + 116
7   iNacho                          0x0000000100119894 -[RKObjectSerializer serializationForMIMEType:error:] + 116
8   iNacho                          0x000000010010a460 -[RKObjectLoader prepareURLRequest] + 632
9   iNacho                          0x00000001000fc8b4 -[RKRequest fireAsynchronousRequest] + 272
10  iNacho                          0x00000001000fcff0 -[RKRequest sendAsynchronously] + 572
11  iNacho                          0x00000001001021ac -[RKRequestQueue loadNextInQueue] + 972
12  iNacho                          0x000000010006545c -[NARReviewManager submitReview:withCompletion:] (NARReviewManager.m:131)
```

The only thing off the top of my head that is different from this REST request is that it sends the bytes of an image to the server while none of the others do that.

The issue seems to be with RESTKit's JSON serialization.

Comment: Any update on this? I'm running into this very same issue right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by upgrading to RestKit 0.2.x, which I might add, was a royal pain in the butt. My next release of that app, I'm hoping to remove Restkit completely.